# Enter a rightview UIImageView to a UITextField

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uikit, uitextfield, ios7

I have a target action that when a button is pressed, I validate the `UITextField`:

```
// Get the text from the UITextField
NSString *nameStr = _name.text;

_name.rightView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"error.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:_name];

if (nameStr.length == 0)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Name"
                                                    message:@"You must enter a name."
                                               delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

My `UITextField` are added to the view in `viewDidLoad` like so:

```
[self.view addSubview:_name];
```

How do I make a rightView `UIImageView` appear?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you sure you are not missing the `UITextField` frame ? And are you setting the `rightViewMode` ?

This is an example i just wrote seem to be working fine.

```
UITextField *rightField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 50)];
rightField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // For testing purpose
rightField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;// Set rightview mode

UIImageView *rightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tick_white_color"]];
rightField.rightView = rightImageView; // Set right view as image view

[self.view addSubview:rightField];
```

Here is the tick image as result :

[image: Right image view]

Answer (score 31):

You have to set `rightViewMode` of the Textfield because  The default value for this property is **UITextFieldViewModeNever**.

so You have to set Mode from following,

```
   UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing,
   UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing,
   UITextFieldViewModeAlways
```

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 3.To show image before placeholder text in `UITextField`

```
func setPaddingView(strImgname: String,txtField: UITextField){
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: strImgname))
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: imageView.image!.size.width , height: imageView.image!.size.height)
        let paddingView: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 30))
        paddingView.addSubview(imageView)
        txtField.leftViewMode = .always
        txtField.leftView = paddingView
    }
```

**To call Function**

```
self.setPaddingView(strImgname: "mail", txtField: txtEmail)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Solution in Swift 3:**

```
class CustomText: UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var rightImage : UIImage?{
        didSet{
            self.rightView = UIImageView(image: rightImage)
            // select mode -> .never .whileEditing .unlessEditing .always
            self.rightViewMode = .always
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you have two or more field** then try this code! its working for me.

```
dropDownImageViewForTextField1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
dropDownImageViewForTextField1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown_n_icon.png"];

dropDownImageViewForTextField2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
dropDownImageViewForTextField2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown_n_icon.png"];


txtField1.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
txtField1.rightView = dropDownImageViewForTextField1;

txtField2.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
txtField2.rightView = dropDownImageViewForTextField2;
```

Do check 2 things

1. `txtField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways`
2. Separate `imageView` for each `textField`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** with `@IBDesignable` and **Swift 3**

Firstly, you can create `@IBDesignable` for `UITextField` like this.

```
@IBDesignable extension UITextField{

    @IBInspectable var setImageName: String {
            get{
                return ""
            }
            set{
                let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: newValue)!
                self.rightView = imageView
                self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        }

    }
```

**Note**: You must be write **get** and **set** points for `@IBInspactable` block because **Swift** has warn to apply getter and **setter** together. We've not need to use the get statement, so returned empty string. Also the attribute name has include Button but not confuse, its a mistake.

Then click the `UITextField` on `StoryBoard` and give the spesific image name to the **setAButtonImageName** attribute.

[image]

Then you will get the following result

[image]

The other situation is the create rightView with seems like has **right margin**

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

You can use a `UIView` as **container** than can add the `UIImageView` into the this `UIView`. In here, you must calculate the **right margin**, container view's **width** and `UIImageViews' width.

```
@IBInspectable var setImageName: String {
        get{
            return ""
        }
        set{
            let containerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:50, height: self.frame.height))
            let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: newValue)!
            containerView.addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.center = containerView.center
            self.rightView = containerView
            self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        }
    }
```